# sbt dist task fails with maximum delay error

Tags: playframework, frameworks, sbt, task

I am trying to create a standalone zip for my play 2.4 app. When I execute dist task on sbt command prompt, I get the below error. Is there way to pass the max delay to dist task, or specify it in some config file in sbt? Thanks.

```
[com.mycompany.myportal] $ dist
[info] Packaging C:\shevatki\stash\ssh\myportal\target\scala-2.11\com.mycompany.myportall_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-s
ources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote C:\shevatki\stash\ssh\myportal\target\scala-2.11\com.mycompany.myportall_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Packaging C:\shevatki\stash\ssh\myportal\target\scala-2.11\com.mycompany.myportall_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.j
ar ...
[info] Optimizing JavaScript with RequireJS
[info] Done packaging.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:webPipeline for the full       output.
[error] (*:webPipeline) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Task  scheduled with [53784000] seconds delay, which is too far in futu
re, maximum delay is [21474835] seconds
[error] Total time: 93 s, completed 20-Jan-2016 12:26:23
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got it resolved. The problem was not with dist tasks max delay, it was the large number of files sitting in the node_modules folder which was created when I was testing my javascript with karma.
The Optimizing Javascript and RequireJS step was trying to optimize stuff inside node_modules folder.

I deleted the node_modules folder and the dist command completed successfully.